# Best way to make my models reusable in other application Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I'm currently working on two different yii2 project templates. Relevant with my question, those projects have the same set of models, and ahead of time, I know that those models can also be used in different yii2 applications. So I'm thinking if there are any ways, that the models can be a separate project / module that can just be imported / called / installed into different applications, and use it just like how we declare a namespace into a class? Is yii2 has a special pattern for that?

Comment: Create extended repository and make a package for composer.

Comment: Thanks @SiZE, can you give me an example on how I can do that?

Comment: Create a github repo and follow instructions from https://packagist.org